# Custom UIProgressView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

I'm using a `UIProgressView` in my application, which is working great right now. But I want to make it larger (height-wise) and color it a different color.

I'm looking to use [`PDColoredProgressView`](https://github.com/PascalW/PDColoredProgressview) for the color, and alter the `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method to change the height, however I can't decide where I would actually alter the height. Any suggestions on what to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out you can resize it like any other view.

```
[coloredProgressView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 25)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the frame side didn't seem to work for me. Setting the transform to a CGAffineTransformMakeScale() can scale it up - not sure if that causes any other problems though.

Answer (score 0):

To change the height of progressView try below code: ( works with Swift 5 )

`progressView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 4)`   // y present the wanted height

and 1 present the current width, so if you change it to 3 then it will mean current width x 2